# Pyspark and BigQuery using two different project-ids in Google Dataproc

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to run some pyspark jobs using Google Dataproc with different project Ids without success so far. I'm newbie with pyspark and Google Cloud but I've followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example) example and runs well (if the BigQuery dataset is either public or belongs to my GCP project, which is ProjectA). Input parameters look like this:

```
bucket = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.system.bucket')
projectA = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.project.id')
input_directory ='gs://{}/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_input'.format(bucket)

conf = {
# Input Parameters
'mapred.bq.project.id': projectA,
'mapred.bq.gcs.bucket': bucket,
'mapred.bq.temp.gcs.path': input_directory,
'mapred.bq.input.project.id': 'projectA',
'mapred.bq.input.dataset.id': 'my_dataset',
'mapred.bq.input.table.id': 'my_table',
}

# Load data in from BigQuery.
table_data = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
'com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat',
'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
'com.google.gson.JsonObject',
conf=conf)
```

But what I need is to run a job from a BQ dataset of a ProjectB (I have credentials to query it), so when setting the input parameters, which look like this:

```
conf = {
# Input Parameters
'mapred.bq.project.id': projectA,
'mapred.bq.gcs.bucket': bucket,
'mapred.bq.temp.gcs.path': input_directory,
'mapred.bq.input.project.id': 'projectB',
'mapred.bq.input.dataset.id': 'the_datasetB',
'mapred.bq.input.table.id': 'the_tableB',
}
```

and try to load data in from BQ, my script keeps running infinitely. How should I set it up properly?

FYI, after running the [example](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example) I mentioned before, I can see that 2 carpets (shard-0 and shard-1) are created in Google Storage and contain the corresponding BQ data, but with my job only  shard-0 is created and it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to my co-worker Dennis and here is his suggestion:

---

"Hmm, not sure, it should work. They might want to test with "bq" CLI inside the master node to manually try some "bq extract" job of the projectB table into their GCS bucket since that's all the connector is doing under the hood.

If I had to guess I'd suspect they only meant their personal username has the credentials to query projectB, but the default service account of projectA might not have the query permissions. Everything inside Dataproc VMs act on behalf of the compute service account assigned to the VMs, not the end-user.

They can

gcloud compute instances describe -m

and somewhere in there it lists the service-account email address."